# How do I create a loop that stops eventually

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, count

So far I have this code.

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//Creating the scanner

        int number;

        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer. Enter '-1' to quit.");//Asking the user to input a number
        number = scan.nextInt();//Scanning for the number

        if(number>0);{
            boolean prime = true;
            for(int j = 2; j <= number/2; ++j)
            {
                if(number % j == 0)//To see if the number is prime
                    {
                        prime = true;//If the equation is true, it's a prime number
                        break;
                    }
             }
             if (prime)//If its a prime number
                 System.out.println(number + " is a prime number.");
             else//If it is not a prime number
                 System.out.println(number + " is not a prime number.");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not looping correctly. I will input something and it will print the result an infinate amount of times. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I added a solution for you. Just as an observation your code has a bug: 8 and 9 are not a prime numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach for you:

I added some comments in order to make it readable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//Creating the scanner

        int number = 0;
        //List to save all the numbers you write
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer. Enter '-1' to quit.");//Asking the user to input a number
        //This loop going to repeat until met the condition
        while(number != -1) {
            number = scan.nextInt();//Scanning for the number


            if(number>0){
                boolean prime = true;
                for(int j = 2; j <= number/2; ++j)
                {
                    if(number % j == 0)//To see if the number is prime
                        {
                            prime = false;
                            break;
                        }
                 }
                 if (prime)//If its a prime number
                     System.out.println(number + " is a prime number.");
                 else//If it is not a prime number
                     System.out.println(number + " is not a prime number.");
               //We save the number
               numbers.add(number);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your numbers were");
        numbers.forEach(System.out::println);


    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a positive integer. Enter '-1' to quit.
3
3 is a prime number.
5
5 is a prime number.
7
7 is a prime number.
8
8 is not a prime number.
31
31 is a prime number.
33
33 is not a prime number.
-1
-1 is a prime number.
Your numbers were
3
5
7
8
31
33
-1
```

Comment: Im having some trouble with this. I'm getting this error "Multiple markers at this line. The list cannot be resolved to a type. Array List cannot be resolved to a type." For the line that reads: "List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();" I'm not sure why. I copied and pasted it from what you wrote here.

Comment: I added the imports for those objects

Comment: Actually you almost have it. Just invert the logic on your conditional. I will update the code.

Comment: Done. Just add the number if it's greater than 0. If this works for you, please accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no loop in your program.
you can use:

```
do{

//read number
//Rest of your code that was inside the if- clause
}while(number>0)
```

instead of your `if(number>0)`

So you have to move the part where you read the number INSIDE the loop.
The do-while-loop is just like a normal while loop, but checks the condition AFTER the first run. You want that so you can read the number inside the loop and then check it at the end of the loop.
For usability you might also want to put the line that tells the user what to do ("insert -1 to quit") inside the loop. So you move both 2 lines of code inside.

Comment: I added this in the code, but it just prints the result a million times. Am i setting up the while loop wrong?